# What is the difference between restarting the computer once and restarting the computer twice?

Tags: windows, performance, reboot, lag

I was noticing that when I restart my computer for the first time, it is "less clogged", and immediately after restarting I restart it again and it feels even "less clogged".

This made me wonder,  from a technological point of view, how *different* can restarting a computer once, be from restarting a computer multiple times?

From my inexperience, I really cannot understand why is restarting a computer twice going to fix a problem that restarting it once didn't solve. What's the explanation here?

==
I use Windows Vista Home Premium but the quesiton I'm asking is actually related to the Windows family in general.

Comment: I've definitely read this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/2467/why-does-restarting-a-computer-fix-things

Comment: Define "clogged"

Comment: @Moab "laggy": basically everything feels slow, the computer seems to hang and not respond.

Comment: I have never noticed multiple reboots to boost performance, I have solved a few weird problems with multiple reboots in Windows XP though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Cloggy" is a subjective word.  At work, we baseline the computers using Performance monitor.  Then we compare current performance against what we know for sure is a clean computer.  The human senses are easily tricked.  Just ask a magician.

To get a easy quantitative measure of your computer, I suggest you start up Performance Monitor.  Click the Data Collector Sets and select *System Performance*.  It will record a host of counters once a second indefinitely, or until you sleep/hibernate/shutdown your computer. Then run your computer through a daily routine. At the end of the day, load up the graphs.

Windows scales the graphs for you.  If you need help deciphering the counters, upload it here.

Without more information, cloggy could be anything from LA "fog" to friggin MT Vesuvius.

Comment: It still haven't changed anything. If you are asking if it is **possible**, then yes, anything is **possible**.  But semantically, I think you are asking if it is likely.  Am I correct?

Comment: yes basically I was wondering what may be some of the reasons restarting once is any different from restarting twice.

Comment: In a general case, there is no difference.  But without more specific info, or even quantitative info, we can only generalize and assume.  And you know what happens when we assume. . .